# Progress or animation circle arround imagevew

Tags: android, animation, imageview, android-animation

I want to draw circular progress with animation around imageview.Depending on % percentage value as input.
For example,If I give 70% it should draw 70%(252 degree) circle around imageview.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same situation once, try to use this Circular Progress View https://github.com/rahatarmanahmed/CircularProgressView , you can set the percentage each time the upload is progressing.

Answer (score 0):

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1446
It would help to create circle progress indicator. You can find the Github link from above.

Answer (score 0):

There is a widget available from here: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1446
which will give you the functionality for making a Circular Progress View which draws the arc-angle based on your progress. There is a step-by-step guide for including it in your project.

To get the ImageView in the center of your progrss circle, you can simply use a RelativeLayout to place it exactly where you need. In this example, I placed the ImageView in the center of the screen. Here is the layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.robert.androidmodule.MainActivity">


<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="100"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circle_progress_background" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/circle_progress_bar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circle_progress_foreground"
    android:rotation="-90" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In this example, I used the basic android icon.

[Here is a picture of it working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOXFe.png)

Hope this helps!